# Java class diagram E meaning

Tags: java

I have to create Java program from this class diagram for a school homework, but I dont know what the type of (E) means. Does it mean that is extends the parent?

How should I create these ATTACKER, DEFFENDER variables, when they dont have any type?

[image: class diagram]

Comment: Probably means Enum.

Comment: Does this help? [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think E means Enum (Enumeration) in this case.
So with correct implementation your PlayerPosition and Gender variables could be the values defined only by the enum instances.